# How to properly conditionally render child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following components : (AddBookPanel contains the AddBookForm)

I need to have the ability to display the form on click of the 'AddBookButton', and also
have the ability to hide the form while clicking the 'x' button (img in AddBookForm component), however the component doesn't seem to load properly, what could be wrong here? What do you think is the best way to organize this?

```
import { AddBookButton } from './AddBookButton';
import { AddBookForm } from './AddBookForm';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const AddBookPanel = () => {
  const [addBookPressed, setAddBookPressed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setAddBookPressed(!addBookPressed)}>
        <AddBookButton />
      </div>
      <AddBookForm initialFormActive={addBookPressed} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface AddBookFormProps {
  initialFormActive: boolean;
}

export const AddBookForm: React.FC<AddBookFormProps> = ({
  initialFormActive,
}) => {
  const [isFormActive, setIsFormActive] = useState(initialFormActive);

  return (
    <>
      {isFormActive && (
        <div className="fixed box-border h-2/3 w-1/3 border-4 left-1/3 top-24 bg-white border-slate-600 shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex justify-between bg-slate-400">
            <div>
              <p className="text-4xl my-5 mx-6">Add a new Book</p>
            </div>
            <div className="h-16 w-16 my-3 mx-3">
              <button onClick={() => setIsFormActive(!isFormActive)}>
                <img
                  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg/1200px-OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg.png"
                  alt="close-button"
                  className="object-fit"
                ></img>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex-col">
            <div className="flex justify-between my-10 ml-5 text-xl">
              <input type="text" placeholder="book name"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: That was right? what is problem?

Comment: When i click "AddBookButton", the form does not show itself

Comment: Does the screen blink oddly when rendering back and forth, or potentially one direction?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery  I could not spot any such behavior

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @sushildlh There are none that appear after clicking the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always rendering the `AddBookForm`. That means in the initial render the `useState` is called with `false`. Since you never call `setIsFormActive` it is now stuck as "do not render".

Just don't use the `useState` and use the property `initialFormActive` directly. And maybe rename it to `isFormActive`. Let the parent handle the state change.

```
import { AddBookButton } from './AddBookButton';
import { AddBookForm } from './AddBookForm';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const AddBookPanel = () => {
  const [addBookPressed, setAddBookPressed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setAddBookPressed(!addBookPressed)}>
        <AddBookButton />
      </div>
      <AddBookForm initialFormActive={addBookPressed} onClose={() => setAddBookPressed(false)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';

interface AddBookFormProps {
  initialFormActive: boolean;
  onColse: () => void;
}

export const AddBookForm: React.FC<AddBookFormProps> = ({
  initialFormActive,
  onClose,
}) => {
  // const [isFormActive, setIsFormActive] = useState(initialFormActive); don't use this frozen state, allow the parent to control visibility

  return (
    <>
      {initialFormActive && (
        <div className="fixed box-border h-2/3 w-1/3 border-4 left-1/3 top-24 bg-white border-slate-600 shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex justify-between bg-slate-400">
            <div>
              <p className="text-4xl my-5 mx-6">Add a new Book</p>
            </div>
            <div className="h-16 w-16 my-3 mx-3">
              <button onClick={() => onClose()}>
                <img
                  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg/1200px-OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg.png"
                  alt="close-button"
                  className="object-fit"
                ></img>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex-col">
            <div className="flex justify-between my-10 ml-5 text-xl">
              <input type="text" placeholder="book name"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, I still need to somehow change the state to inactive inside the form (by clicking the img button which is a close button)

Comment: then pass in a callback.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain that callback

Comment: I'd rename a few of those variables, though.

Comment: What are your suggestions?

Comment: initialFormActive => isVisible, or show. And [addBookPressed, setAddBookPressed] to [showForm, setShowForm]. Or something along that line

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is in how you tied `initialFormActive` to inner state of `AddBookForm` component. When looking at useState inside `AddBookForm` it is clear that prop `initialFormActive` only affects your initial state, and when looking at your parent component I can clearly see that you passed false as value for `initialFormActive` prop, thus initializing state inside `AddBookForm` with false value(form will stay hidden). Then you expect when you click on button, and when prop value changes(becomes true), that your `<AddBookForm />` will become visible, but it will not because you just used initial value(false) from prop and after that completely decoupled from prop value change.

Since you want to control visibility outside of component, then you should attach two props to AddBookForm, `isVisible` and `toggleVisibiliy`. And do something like this:

```
 export const AddBookPanel = () => {
  const [addBookPressed, setAddBookPressed] = useState(false);
  const toggleAddBookPressed = () => setAddBookPressed(p => !p);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setAddBookPressed(!addBookPressed)}>
        <AddBookButton />
      </div>
      <AddBookForm isVisible={addBookPressed} toggleVisibility={toggleAddBookPressed } />
    </div>
  );
```

};

```
export const AddBookForm: React.FC<AddBookFormProps> = ({
  isVisible, toggleVisibility
}) => {

  return (
    <>
      {isVisible&& (
        <div className="fixed box-border h-2/3 w-1/3 border-4 left-1/3 top-24 bg-white border-slate-600 shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex justify-between bg-slate-400">
            <div>
              <p className="text-4xl my-5 mx-6">Add a new Book</p>
            </div>
            <div className="h-16 w-16 my-3 mx-3">
              <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>
                <img
                  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg/1200px-OOjs_UI_icon_close.svg.png"
                  alt="close-button"
                  className="object-fit"
                ></img>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex-col">
            <div className="flex justify-between my-10 ml-5 text-xl">
              <input type="text" placeholder="book name"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```